# Chipmunk iphonestatic command error

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, chipmunk

so, I just downloaded the latest Version of chipmunk, and when I run the iphonestatic.command from finder I get the following output in my Command Line

```
    Last login: Wed Oct 26 22:15:59 on ttys001
PS1:~ Thermo$ /Users/Thermo/Desktop/Programs\ software/Software/iphonestatic.command ; exit;
usage: dirname path
Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphoneos4.3

xcodebuild: error: 'Chipmunk6.xcodeproj' does not exist.
logout
```

I can't get the script to build the proper files, and have been trying to figure this out for a while,
thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! After a stroke of luck I discovered that you could cause that bug by having a space in your path somewhere.

The first line of the script does this to set the working directory to the parent directory of the script when running it from the finder:

```
cd `dirname $0`
```

It barfs when you have a space in the path somewhere. Not exactly certain how to fix it... The workaround is easy enough though, just make sure you put it somewhere it won't have a space.

edit: Looks like it just needs multiple sets of parens:

```
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
```